# Codeigniter Active Record: is it possible to remove the brakets around the table name

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, activerecord

I am using codeigniter to produce a left join of two tables, but need to remove the brackets that active record applies to the table name. you know `SELECT blah FROM ('some table')` I really need these brackets to disappear.

here is my input array:

```
$retrieve_arr = array(
    'table' => 'entries',
    'select' => array('entries.entry_id', 'entries.score', 'sc_users.name', 'clients.name'),
    'joins' => array(
        'clients' => 'entries.client_id = clients.client_id',
        'sc_users' => 'entries.sc_user_id = sc_users.sc_user_id'
    ),
    'joinType' => 'left',
    'where' => 'null'
    );
```

here is my model:

```
$retrieve = new Data();
if($get_arr['select'] != 'null')
{
    $query = $retrieve->db->select($get_arr['select']);
}
foreach($get_arr['joins'] as $additional => $value)
{
    $retrieve->db->join($additional, $value, $get_arr['joinType']);
}
if($get_arr['where'] != 'null')
{
    foreach ($get_arr['where'] as $name => $value) 
    {
        $retrieve->db->where($name, $value);
    }
}
$query = $retrieve->db->get($get_arr['table']);
$queryData = $query->result_array();

return $queryData;
```

and here is what my query string:

```
SELECT `entries`.`entry_id`, `entries`.`score`, `sc_users`.`name`, `clients`.`name` FROM (`entries`) LEFT JOIN `sc_users` ON `entries`.`sc_user_id` = `sc_users`.`sc_user_id` LEFT JOIN `clients` ON `sc_users`.`client_id` = `clients`.`client_id`Array
```

I have been looking for this for a while so your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: I would just like to note that the word array at teh end of the query string is actually form something else i was echo-ing out.

Comment: Why don't you want the parenthesis in your SQL string?  What problem are you trying to solve?  (This wouldn't happen to be a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), would it?) That's a 100% valid SQL query.

Comment: it is a sort of XY problem , but this is the only solution that would not put me into conflict with other developers. The Query does work, but only pulls out clients.name and not sc_users.name , when I make a query string in phpMyAdmin if I put brackets around the tablename SELECT * FROM ('blah') the query wont pull out both the names but if i take the brackets away when i enter the string it will pull both out.

Comment: Is `$get_arr` the same array as `$retrieve_arr`?  Because I don't think `db->select(array())` actually works.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the ` backticks, in the Select() portion, use a FALSE as the second parameter (refer to the Users Guide for more info)

Comment: No, its the brackets that would be used for the table name in the from portion.

Comment: ah, the parenthesis. 1) why do you need them off? Can't think of any sql reasons 2) just use the simple $this->db->query($sql) method, instead of Active Record

Comment: Hi, thanks, i was hoping that would not be the solution, if you read the comment i added about 20 mins ago it explains how i came to the perenthesis conclusion. another solution would be to change the name in the table so they aren't both identical.however your solution is time consuming and the other is supposidly contraversial, if you have a third solution, then all would be great!

Comment: Your comment from 20min ago doesn't really make any sense to me; nor does "it's too time consuming", as you could have written raw sql in have the time you spent posting, if that was an actual solution to your db. Suggest your issue is entirely sql & you should start posting more query info that will help solve what sounds like an sql issue